# Regular Expression is being too greedy on alternation operation

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I have the following regular expression which is supposed to match remove operations from a [JSON PATCH](http://jsonpatch.com/) request.

> ({\s*\"op\"\s*:\s*\"remove\",\s*\"path\"\s*:\s*\".*\",\s*\"value\"\s*:\s*([{.*}]|\".*\")\s*})

If I apply this regular expression to

> [{"op":"remove","path":"/emailAddresses","value":[{"emailType":{"code":"E","codeSystemId":"hl7.org"},"emailAddress":"abc@abcdef.com","idWithSource":"abc|817921"}]},{"op":"replace","path":"/emailAddresses","value":[{"idWithSource":"abc|822222"}]}]

I get the following as a match.

> {"op":"remove","path":"/emailAddresses","value":[{"emailType":{"code":"E","codeSystemId":"hl7.org"},"emailAddress":"abc@abcdef.com","idWithSource":"abc|817921"}]},{"op":"replace","path":"/emailAddresses","value":[{"idWithSource":"abc|822222"}

It needs to be just the following:

> {"op":"remove","path":"/emailAddresses","value":[{"emailType":{"code":"E","codeSystemId":"hl7.org"},"emailAddress":"abc@abcde.com","idWithSource":"abc|817921"}]}

If I apply this regular expression to

> [{ "op": "remove", "path": "/drugName", "value": "aadadada" },{ "op":
>   "replace", "path": "/drugName", "value": "Tylenol" }]

I get the following as a match.

> { "op": "remove", "path": "/drugName", "value": "aadadada" },{ "op":
>   "replace", "path": "/drugName", "value": "Tylenol" }

It needs to be just the following:

> { "op": "remove", "path": "/drugName", "value": "aadadada" }

These two examples are the formats that the value field can be in. Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse a JSON. There are a lot of JSON parser for every languages

Comment: Use lazy matching [`\{\s*\"op\"\s*:\s*\"remove\",\s*\"path\"\s*:\s*\".*?\",\s*\"value\"\s*:\s*(\[\{.*?\}\]|\".*?\")\s*\}`](https://regex101.com/r/iY6jA5/2).